# How to set default store view

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have in my magento 2 store view:

- **English**
- **Poland**

After entering the website the shop view is displayed: **English**

But I want display **Poland**, so I have configure this on:

- **store --> Configuration ---> General ---> Default setting ---> Locale and set Poland**.

But not work, anyone know how to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got to **store > all** store  click on **store**  on which you want to change the **store view**

[image]

Now Select your desired Store View. In **Default Store View** Option.